# How to extend ui bootstrap directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

It's pretty much simple to implement with patching the link function in the `$uibTooltip`, but I'd like not to modify thirdparty library and just to extend directive.

I need to show a trigger "show" tooltip only if text has an ellipsis (e.g. `blabla...`).

The use case is the same as on ui-bootstrap page, but with new attribute:

```
<input type="text" value="Click me!" uib-tooltip="See?" tooltip-trigger="focus" tooltip-placement="right"/>
```

New attribute is:
`tooltip-ellipsis="true"`.

Ellipsis can be detected only before the trigger event and after linking state, of course.

So, there are ways:

- `provider.decorator` -> `$delegate` - I think it's not an option, I need to modify the link and I have no idea how to do it with decorate.
- wrapper for `uib-tooltip`, but I can't find the way to get options in the link of my wrapper.

Comment: If you aren't sure how to rewrite it using a decorator wouldn't `ng-if` or `ng-switch` do what you need? Provide sample markup for usage. Can also use a directive to compile tooltip if it is applicable to value

Comment: @charlietfl Updated the question.

Comment: still not quite clear where the value with ellipsis  is...or exactly what condition is needed to use tooltip or not. This should be simple using `ng-if`. A simple demo would also help

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will get what you want here : http://thaiat.github.io/blog/2014/03/10/extending-an-existing-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: @WarrenReilly nope, doesn't suite for me.

Comment: @charlietfl I'd like to add one attribute, the value of attribute will be passed  explicitly from the parent scope to the directive, I'm not sure what is not clear. ng-if is not working in this case since the new directive should be with restriction to `A`, as I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If all you want is to decide if the tooltip should be displayed on focus or not based on an attribute from the parent scope you shouldn't need to extend the directive, you have the `tooltip-enable` attribute that does just that.

Instead of doing

```
<input type="text" value="Click me!" uib-tooltip="See?" tooltip-trigger="focus" tooltip-placement="right" tolltip-ellipsis="true"/>
```

do:

```
<input type="text" value="Click me!" uib-tooltip="See?" tooltip-trigger="focus" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-enable="hasEllipsis"/>
```

and set your $scope.hasEllipsis accordingly. See the [documentation plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) for an example

**Solution 2**

Set your tooltip-trigger event to none when there's not an ellipsis in your text. This should be trivial in your controller.

**Solution - 3 (IF you really want to add a new attribute)**

You can create another directive with the same name and add your own link function that modifies the value of the first scope.

See my [modified plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YVt7X9QqvKBfrIz8ML6M?p=preview) extending the `counter` directive with a new `shouldCount` attribute that modifies the original value and prevents the count.

(If that's all you're trying to achieve **I DO NOT RECOMMEND DOING THIS**. Use solutions 1 or 2)

Comment: Honestly I don't like all the solutions above. I'd like to find another and more appropriate.

Comment: I'm confused. What is there not to like? Can you elaborate on why would you not want to use the built in attribute that does what you want and is in the official documentation(solution 1)?

Comment: you just explained how to implement approaches that I already suggested. I don't see that these approaches are correct and I'm looking for another solution. I'm not sure, if it even exists, but points 1 and 2 from your answer is not very helpful for me. Sorry if my question is not pretty clear for you.

Comment: This answer gives you a way of enabling/disabling the tooltip at any point, AND shows you how to combine both broken approaches that you suggested to solve your problem. I suggest you elaborate your question and add what you're looking for or I think it'll be difficult for the community to help you.

Comment: maybe you're right, I didn't say that your answer is wrong, but I feel that there should be more simple solution and I don't know anything about it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution to this problem, not sure if it's the best, but it works

HTML

```
<div elements-overflow-ellipsis>
    <span class="font-bold no-margins"> {{name | translate}} </span>:
</div>
```

CSS

```
.basic-overflow-ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('dcElements')
        .directive('elementsOverflowEllipsis', [ '$compile', function( $compile ) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                priority: 1000,
                controller: ElementsOverflowEllipsisController,
                controllerAs: '$ctrl'
            }
        } ] );

    ElementsOverflowEllipsisController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$compile', '$element' ];

    function ElementsOverflowEllipsisController( $scope, $compile, $element ) {
        var $ctrl = this;
        $ctrl.isEllipsisActive = isEllipsisActive;

        activate();

        function isEllipsisActive() {
            return ( $element[0].offsetWidth < $element[0].scrollWidth );
        };

        function activate() {
            $element.addClass( 'basic-overflow-ellipsis' );
            if ( !$element.attr( 'uib-tooltip' ) ) {
                $element.attr( 'uib-tooltip', $element.text() );
                $element.attr( 'tooltip-enable', "$ctrl.isEllipsisActive()" );
                $compile( $element )( $scope );
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm not sure that directive with priority 1000 will be invoked after all the items will be rendered, but I believe it works